# Only include if exists

Tags: gulp

I am looking to include a file in gulp only if it exists, when I am compiling, for development. Currently I have the following:

```
gulp.task('compile:js:development', function() {
  return gulp.src([
    'src/js/**/*.js',
  ]).pipe(concat('dist.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('compiled/js/'))
});
```

I need to add another file to this array, but only if that file exists. I have seen `gulp-if` But I don't think that has the capability I am looking for.

I would also like to warn the developer that this file doesn't exist, when compiling for development in the console.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Gulp is just a node application, so you can use any node functions in your gulpfile. You can easily check existence of a file using [fs.exists()](http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_exists_path_callback)

```
gulp.task('compile:js:development', function() {
  var fs = require('fs'),
      files = ['src/js/**/*.js'],
      extraFile = 'path/to/other/file';

  if (fs.existsSync(extraFile)) {
    files.push(extraFile);
  } else {
    console.log('FILE DOES NOT EXIST');
  }

  return gulp.src(files)
    .pipe(concat('dist.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('compiled/js/'))
});
```

Comment: Can you provide an example in how one would use this in a gulp task to compile js?

Comment: The first options in `gulp.src` can be either a `String` or `Array` and not existent files are ignored, so I think that this could be simplified to `gulp.src(['src/js/**/*.js', 'path/to/other/file'])`

Comment: @PaoloMoretti that would work. but OP said they want to warn the developer if the file does not exist.

Comment: @BrianGlaz Oh, sorry I didn't catch that. In that case I guess you have to manually check if the file exist. You could also use [`gulp-expect-file`](https://www.npmjs.org/package/gulp-expect-file) :)